Cannot debug visual studio projects - SetSite failed for package [ExtensionsPackage](null)
For the past month or so, this error keeps popping up and affecting my ability to debug.
VS Dialog Image
I can still build and test the web project in a browser, so studio is running, but as soon as I start debugging, a dialog pops up stating that the 'ExtensionsPackage' package did not load correctly. The dialog has Yes/No buttons to indicate whether it should continue to be shown, but neither works - it just makes the app freeze...but just the dialog portion.  My app is still running in the browser and it's functional, but I cannot debug.  And if I hit an exception in the app, it can't be viewed/addressed because the IDE is frozen.  I've repaired vs, reinstalled, restructured my solutions (which worked at first, but then it started occurring again).  The activity log has this as it's last entry:
  <entry>
    <record>490</record>
    <time>2024/12/21 12:08:10.371</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [ExtensionsPackage](null)</description>
    <guid>{D40A86AA-B995-46A6-9C90-02D38AD8637E}</guid>
    <hr>0x80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

You can run sfc /scannow to  repair missing or corrupted system files to make sure your OS is fine.

As the error message indicates,

The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension.

To narrow down the issue, i would suggest try the following:

Open a Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio (as administrator) and type the following command:

devenv /setup
devenv /clearcache
devenv /resetuserdata
devenv /updateconfiguration


Clear Visual Studio cache.(e.g: Visual Studio 2022)

%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17_xxxx\ComponentModelCache


Run Visual Studio in SafeMode mode, this switch prevents all third-party VSPackages from loading when Visual Studio starts, allowing stable execution, check if the error appears again.

 devenv /SafeMode

If the error message disappears then this error is caused by a specific extension. You can type keyword Extensions and find detailed information in your ActivitlyLog file. Then disable the extension via Extensions->Manage Extensions menu.
